# Broadcasted intent not being received by system app

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest

I have a `BroadcastReciever` in a system app that I want to send an `Intent` to (for testing purposes as I'm modding that system app).

The `AndroidManifest.xml` of the system app looks like this:

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name">
    <receiver android:label="StateReceiver" android:name=".abstractor.StateReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.sec.android.contextaware.HEADSET_PLUG" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.LOCALE_CHANGED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.bluetooth.headset.profile.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />                
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <provider android:name=".manager.LoggingDataProvider" android:authorities="com.sec.android.contextaware.manager.LoggingDataProvider" />
</application>
```

I use a test app and check if the target system app indeed can receive that intent with:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("com.sec.android.contextaware.HEADSET_PLUG");

PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : pm.queryBroadcastReceivers(bt, 0)) {
    Log.d("APP: ", resolveInfo.toString());
}
```

and get back a `ResolveInfo` with the system app's info, so it should be able to receive the intent. I then broadcast the intent with:

```
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

However nothing happens, the intent is not received. I have full control of the target system app's manifest file and code. Is it possible to somehow get the intent across?
Device is rooted.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried sendStickyBroadcast(intent) ?  After registering a null receiver you should be able to retrieve the last one sent.  Not sure it it will help.  BTW what is the target system app that you are sending to? It its not getting there its either because its not allowed or because something is wrong with the way you are addressing it: intent.setAction("com.sec.android.contextaware.HEADSET_PLUG");

I am guessing that either com.sec.android.contextaware.HEADSET_PLUG is not permission allowed to receive or the addressing is incorrect.  Doublecheck com.sec.android.contextaware.HEADSET_PLUG in particular.

Comment: Target is ContextAwareService.apk, a Samsung service that listens to some events and displays stuff in the notification bar. Will try your suggestion tomorrow, time for bed now. ;)

Comment: Didn't work. The AndroidManifest.xml above is from the target, shouldn't it be able to recieve "com.sec.android.contextaware.HEADSET_PLUG" from anyone?